# What banks or credit unions local to Texas are most convenient?

Tags: united-states, banking, credit-unions, texas

I'm researching credit unions and banks in Texas due to the recent announcement of Bank of America's $5/mo fee for debit card use.

I'm very mobile. I live in College Station, TX, primarily, but have business in Houston, TX, Austin, TX, and San Antonio, TX that keeps me there for extended times regularly. I often use a rewards credit card that is with Bank of America, but I'm not adverse to paying it off and closing it. My second most used card is my B of A debit card. I rarely carry cash due after being mugged several times.

I'd happily sign up with a credit union, but haven't found one that has branches in all three cities that I frequent that I also qualify for. I do not qualify for USAA as far as I know. I mainly need a debit card and credit card that won't charge me fees.

Comment: I had a credit union for years that didn't have a branch in the city I lived in. In the age of Internet banking it doesn't seem that important anymore.

Comment: @Karl look into USAA again, they changed their policy a while back. If not, then look into Ally Bank, i have an account with them as well for savings, but they are a good bank as well. Pretty competitive with USAA.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a local credit union that is part of the co-op network.   This lets me use a bunch of atms with no fees and I can even go into credit union service centers around the country and do more complicated transactions.

http://www.co-opfs.org/public/locators/culocator/index.cfm

My credit union is only in Colorado and I've used many ATMs and branches in other states while traveling.

Answer (score 0):

Alliant Credit union is in the midwest, but you can easily join from anywhere.  They have has lots of ATM affiliates you can use.

A good non-credit union answer is Charles Schwab

1. Deposit online for both with a scanner
2. Deposit via an Android or iPhone app for Schawb
3. Schwab will reimburse 100% of your ATM fees each month
4. Both have pretty good online banking
5. Neither charge me any unreasonable fees, or fees for using the cards

How much do you really need to visit a branch, especially if you can deposit online?